# how to create DBMS_JOB execute every monday at 04:00

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create job which executes every monday on 04:00 with the script

```
declare
 job number;
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit( job,
                      'CALC_LAST_WEEK_STAT();',
                      to_date('03-07-2017 04:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                      trunc('NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), "MONDAY") + 4/24'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
  commit;
end;
/
```

but i have error PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBMIT'

Comment: `declare
 job number;
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit( job,
                      'CALC_LAST_WEEK_STAT();',
                      to_date('03-07-2017 04:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                      'NEXT_DAY(trunc(SYSDATE,"dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss"),"MONDAY")+4/24');
  commit;
end;
/`

Comment: Try `trunc(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'MONDAY')) + 4/24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at [the documentation for DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_job.htm#ARPLS66583) you will see that the datatype for `interval` is `VARCHAR2`. You are passing a date  whereas `SUBMIT()` expects the formula for working out the time of the next run.

So that would be

```
q'[(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MONDAY') + 4/24)]'
```